# Instability of RL circuit

Tags: inductor

I have the following circuit

[image]

The transfer function is $$H_K(s)=\frac{R}{Ls+R}$$
I have three questions.

- Given \$s=\sigma+j\omega\$, \$\omega=2\pi f\$ but what is the physical meaning of \$\sigma\$?
- It should have a pole in \$s=-\frac{R}{L}\$ but the time domain equation is a sum of an exponential with a negative exponent plus a sin and a cos, there should be no instability regardless of the frequency (and also intuitively).
- To be sure, \$s=-\frac{R}{L}\$ is imaginary or real?

Comment: How can s be negative?

Comment: I found it written here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL_circuit#Poles_and_zeros

Comment: @MissMulan, Generally, s is a complex quantity, the real and imaginary parts may be positive, negative, or zero

Comment: For your 1st order transfer function, there is a real pole at \$s=-\frac{R}{L}\$ and the unit impulse response will be \$\frac{R}{L}e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\$. If the transfer function were 2nd order underdamped, there would also be a sinusoid, which would decay exponentially. Everything comes down to Euler’s relationship linking the exponential and the sinusoids.